# Firebase subcollection

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Firebase Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIari.png)

I'm trying to make a books app that I can update and add new books through firebase. I've books collection (to show books cover on the home screen) and pages as subcollection( will show pages when I select a book). the listener for the books collection work perfectly books covers appear on the home screen but the listener for subcollection doesn't when I select a book the images doesn't appear. here is the listener for the books collection

```
  listener = Firestore.firestore().collection(DatabaseService.booksCollectionCollection).addSnapshotListener({ [weak self] (snapshot, error) in
            
            
            if let error = error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.showAlert(title: "Try again", message: "\(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            } else if
                let snapshot = snapshot {
                
                let bookSnap = snapshot.documents.map { books($0.data())}
              
                self?.booksCollection1 = bookSnap
            }
        })
```

the listener for subcollection (pagesCollection)

```
 listener = Firestore.firestore().collection(DatabaseService.booksCollectionCollection)
           .document(bookS.bookId)
           .collection(DatabaseService.pagesCollection)
           .addSnapshotListener({ [weak self] (snapshot, error) in
           if let error = error {
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self?.showAlert(title: "Try Again", message: error.localizedDescription)
             }
           } else if let snapshot = snapshot {
             let pages = snapshot.documents.map { books($0.data()) }
             self?.collectionPages = pages
           }
         })
         }
```

please help me to figure out where is the problem I've been searching for a solution for days

Comment: Is that TypeScript?

Comment: No. It's swift.

Comment: Please check the official documentation regarding [Get realtime updates with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#swift). Here you will find a good example for swift.

Comment: @marian.vladoi thank you I figure it out